# What's wrong with my delete button function - REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click on the delete button, nothing happens...anyone knows what's wrong. My database is connected and working! I have a `404` error when I click!

Also, I get this: index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique `"key"` prop.

Check the render method of `Allchallenges`.

in `div` (at `Allchallenges.js:54`)    in `Allchallenges` (created by `Context.Consumer`)    in `Route` (at `App.js:23`)    in `Switch` (at `App.js:18`)    in `div` (at `App.js:16`)    in `App` (at `src/index.js:10`)    in `Router` (created by `BrowserRouter`)    in `BrowserRouter` (at `src/index.js:9`)

This is what I have on the API side:

```
//request challenges 
router.get("/allchallenges", (req,res) => {
  Challenge
  .find()
  .then(response => {
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})

//delete challenge
router.get("/allchallenges", (req,res) => {
  Challenge
  .find()
  .then(response => {
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})
```

---

```
import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"
import Challengebox from '../components/Challengebox'
import axios from "axios";

class Allchallenges extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
           challenges: []
        }

        this.onDelete=this.onDelete.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        debugger
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/allchallenges`,
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            let challengeslist = response.data;
            this.setState({challenges: challengeslist})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("You've made an error charles: ",error)
        })
    }

    onDelete(challengeId){
        axios
        .delete(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/allchallenges/${challengeId}`)
        .then(response => {
            this.props.history.push("/allchallenges")
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <div className="challengeoverviewlist">
                    <h1>All challenges</h1>   

                    <div className="challengeboxes">

                    {    
                    this.state.challenges.map(challenge => 
                        (
                            <div className="totalbox">

                                <Challengebox 
                                    key={challenge._id} 
                                    id={challenge._id} 
                                    title={challenge.title} 
                                    description={challenge.description}
                                />

                                <button onClick={() => this.onDelete(challenge._id)}>
                                    Delete
                                </button>

                            </div>
                        ))                                                                      
                    }

                    </div>

                </div>    
            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
}

export default Allchallenges
```

Comment: Add a key prop to `<div className="totalbox">` to solve the key error. `<div className="totalbox" key={challenge._id}>`. As far as 404 is concerned, please check of your API

Comment: thanks. what do you mean with...check of your api?

Comment: I mean that verify that all the request params being sent to server are correct or not. you can see in the chrome devtools network tab to check what request is being sent and verify it against what is expected. 404 means that server didn't find what you were looking for

Comment: did you implement a route for the '/allchallenges' redirection? e.g.: <Route path="/allchallenges" component="Foo" >

Comment: <Route path="/allchallenges" component={Allchallenges} /> is what I have yes

Comment: This is what I have on the API side:
//request challenges
router.get("/allchallenges", (req,res) => {
  Challenge
  .find()
  .then(response => {
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})

//delete challenge
router.get("/allchallenges", (req,res) => {
  Challenge
  .find()
  .then(response => {
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})

Comment: @CharlieVdb edit your answer and add the relevant code/information there - don't do it in here.

Comment: anyone that could have a look at my api side?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `axios.delete` but as far as I can see you don't have any route that handles DELETE.

You need something that looks like this in your router:

```
//delete challenge
router.delete("/allchallenges/:challengeId", (req,res) => {
 // do something with "req.params.challengeId"
})
```

Comment: ok thanks, I updated it! But it is still not working so there must be another issue. Any chance you could have another look?

Answer (score 0):

Please check on the API side, in your code for both `GET` and `DELETE` requests it's been handled as

```js
//delete challenge
router.get("/allchallenges", (req,res) => {
```

That's why when you are calling from front end the API with DELETE method is not present in the backed, hence you are getting `404`.

So at the API side for delete API make it as below

```js
//delete challenge
router.delete("/allchallenges/:challengeId", (req,res) => {
```

Comment: ok thanks, I updated it! But it is still not working so there must be another issue. Any chance you could have another look?

Comment: make the change in API for delete as per my updated answer for `delete` API. Can you try this once.

Comment: Also If from your `DELETE` API also if you are sending all the challenges again, can you once try this 

`onDelete(challengeId){
        axios
        .delete(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/allchallenges/${challengeId}`)
        .then(response => {
            let challengeslist = response.data;
            this.setState({challenges: challengeslist})
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }`